# JavaMail Message.reply(boolean) does not populate recipients

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to write a simple routine to reply to an email with a determined from address and subject, however, for whatever reason the `reply` method is not populating the recipients.

In the following example `rep` is always null, any attempt to call `Transport.send` results in an exception stating there were no recipients.

```
MimeMessage reply = (MimeMessage) message.reply(false);
Address[] rep = reply.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
if (rep == null || rep.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("Reply aborted due to no recipient.");
} else {
    reply.setFrom(from);
    reply.setText(body);
    Transport.send(reply);
}
```

I'm applying the pattern that's demonstrated on the [Oracle jGuru pages](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html) and copied all over the place in various flavours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of [`reply`](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#reply%28boolean%29):

> If replyToAll is set, the new Message will be addressed to all recipients of this message. Otherwise, the reply will be addressed to only the sender of this message (using the value of the getReplyTo method).

So the logical next step would be to check what `message.getReplyTo()` returns. If that returns null, it explains the issue...

Comment: Thanks Jon, I must apologise. I have now added testing for this behaviour though I actually misinterpreted the JavaDoc when I first read it, I figured that it would still reply to the "getFrom()" recipient(s) if "getReplyTo" was null and assumed the "replyToAll" argument only related to Bcc and Cc addresses being added as recipients (much akin to an reply-to-all function on most email clients).